# hyphen between section number and table number in caption

Tags: tables, captions, chngcntr

Using the `chngcntr` package, it is possible to number tables and figures starting from the current section (i.e. The second table of the third section would be Table 3.2). My university wants the separator between the section and the table number to be a hyphen instead:

`Table 3.2` should instead be `Table 3-2`

How should I go about achieving this?

Here is a visual example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{This is the first section}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{This should write ''Table 1-1``}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C \\
    \toprule
    D & E & F \\
    G & H & I \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{This should write ''Table 1-2``}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C \\
    \toprule
    D & E & F \\
    G & H & I \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{This is the second section}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{This should write ''Table 2-1``}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C \\
    \toprule
    D & E & F \\
    G & H & I \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{This should write ''Table 2-2``}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C \\
    \toprule
    D & E & F \\
    G & H & I \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: Unless your TeX distribution is more than 4 years old, you don't need to load the `chngcntr` package in order to make use of `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the instructions

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection-\arabic{table}}
```

in the preamble.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection-\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}

\section{This is the first section}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{This should be ``Table 1-1''\strut}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C \\
    \midrule
    D & E & F \\
    G & H & I \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{This should be ``Table 1-2''\strut}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C \\
    \midrule
    D & E & F \\
    G & H & I \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{This is the second section}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{This should be ``Figure 2-1''\strut}
  \rule{4cm}{2cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht!]
  \centering
  \caption{This should be ``Table 2-1''\strut}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C \\
    \midrule
    D & E & F \\
    G & H & I \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And `\counterwithin*` would spare a redefinition of `\thefigure` that's immediately overridden.

Comment: @egreg - You're right. I guess I was going to leave the OP's code untouched as much as possible.